# ROS node can not import a class

Tags: ros, ros-kinetic, ubuntu

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello everyone,

I am not sure that my problem is ROS related, but I have made a ROS node that was successfully working before I try to import a class inside it.
Now, I get an undefined reference every catkin_make :

```
CMakeFiles/attachPoint.dir/src/attachPoint.cpp.o: In function `main':
attachPoint.cpp:(.text+0x4c5): undefined reference to `Magnet::Magnet(ros::NodeHandle)'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I did try to modify the cmakelist to make it work, but I was not successfull.

This is my main where I get the error :

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <tf/tf.h>
#include "magnet.h"

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    ros::init(argc, argv, "attachPoint");
    ros::NodeHandle nh;

    Magnet mgt = Magnet(nh);
[...]
}
```

Cmakelist :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(approche)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  message_generation
  roscpp
  rospy
  std_msgs
  mavros
  aruco_detect
  geometry_msgs
)

 add_message_files(
    FILES
    posmarker.msg
#   Message2.msg
 )

 generate_messages(
   DEPENDENCIES
   std_msgs
   geometry_msgs
 )

catkin_package(
#  INCLUDE_DIRS include
#  LIBRARIES approche
  CATKIN_DEPENDS roscpp std_msgs aruco_detect mavros message_runtime
#  DEPENDS system_lib
)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

add_executable(attachPoint src/attachPoint.cpp)
target_link_libraries(attachPoint ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

This the header file of my class magnet.h

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <dynamic_reconfigure/IntParameter.h>
#include <std_msgs/Int16.h>

class Magnet
{
public:
    Magnet(ros::NodeHandle mynode);

    void boost(void);

    void off(void);

    void down(void);
    
    int getPWMBoost(void);

    void setPWMBoost(int mypwm);

    int getPWMDown(void);

    void setPWMDown(int mypwm);

private:
    ros::NodeHandle nh;
    ros::Publisher sendOrder_pub;

    std_msgs::Int16 data_magnet;
    void magnet_cb(const std_msgs::Int16::ConstPtr& data);
    ros::Subscriber magnet_sub;
    dynamic_reconfigure::IntParameter sendOrder;

    bool read;
};
```

Best regards.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/318843/ros-node-can-not-import-a-class/) by [oiseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/38651/oiseau/) on ROS Answers with karma: 32 on 2019-03-19

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2019-03-19**:
Please include the `CMakeLists.txt` file in your post!

**Comment by [oiseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/38651/oiseau/) on 2019-03-19**:
Done, don't worry about messages that are not including in the main, I just put the essentials here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I got the answer and that was pretty simple.
I only needed to change this line in the cmakelist :

```
add_executable(attachPoint src/attachPoint.cpp src/magnet.cpp)
target_link_libraries(attachPoint ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

---

Originally posted by [oiseau](https://answers.ros.org/users/38651/oiseau/) with karma: 32 on 2019-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [christophebedard](https://answers.ros.org/users/29634/christophebedard/) on 2019-03-22**:
Yes, usually you list all of your `.cpp` files in `add_executable()`. Only noticed that after everything else!